# topicClient.Send timeout exception

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

I have a topicClient created from messagingfactory using connectionString

MessagingFactory.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString)

MessagingFactory.CreateQueueClient(topicName).

In low band networks i get a timeout exception when sending messages to Azure Topic. Is there a way to change the timeout property?

I know there is a way when we use MessagingFactory.Create() method.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Here's the Code Snippet:

```
MessagingFactorySettings settings = new MessagingFactorySettings {
    settings.OperationTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120)
    };
MessagingFactory messagingFactory = MessagingFactory.Create(connection, settings);
```

and more over - if you need performance critical messaging - ServiceBus also supports the standard Protocol for Messaging - AMQP.

```
settings.TransportType = TransportType.Amqp;
```

BTW, I guess a typo, but just in case - in your code snippet use : CreateTopicClient (not createQueueClient)

Hope it helps!
Sree

Answer (score 0):

For those of you who stumbled here through google. I got a similar problem while using the 'Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus' package in .NET core. I got a time out error when trying

```
await client.SendAsync(message);
```

In my case the problem was that my company was blocking port 5671.
Switching to AmqpWebSockets resolved my issue.
Put this after your connection string.

```
;TransportType=AmqpWebSockets
```